# Just a port forwarding

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat

I have few questions. Maybe somebody can help me.

1. Does port-forwarding work on every router or there are some exceptions?
2. I have TP-LINK TL-MR6400 router (with SIM card in it, it uses a 4G connection). There is a option in router's admin page for port forwarding, port triggering and DMZ and I tried to set it up so many times but it just does not work. According to this website, [You Get Signal - Open port finder](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) - which I use to check if port is open, the port is always closed. Is it because of the type of router? Maybe the router does not support hosting a server behind NAT, after all? or ISP is just blocking all incoming ports?

Anybody had same problem?

I always gave up trying to host a server which is visible on the internet. It just does not work properly.

It appears I have Port-Restricted Cone NAT Router. If it helps.

I first asked the question here https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com, but they told me go rather here as this board is suited more for this type of questions

Maybe the website which I use for checking if port is open is not good. I will use Zenmap.

Comment: 4G connections are usually [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: What carrier are you on? Some carriers, such as Verizon, block ports in hopes of stopping piracy or tunneling to bypass data limits.

Answer (score 2):

4G connections typically don't give you a public IPv4 address of your own, primarily because there aren't enough of them to go around. That makes port forwarding ineffective since no non-reply traffic would get to your router in the first place.

Comment: @DavidSchwarzenegger ... I vote you for Governor sir!!